# Cannot animate png image to fade out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

in my html I have:

```
<div id="testId">
    <img  src="img/Capture.PNG" alt="0" style=" background-color: red; margin-left:50px; "/>
</div>
```

In javascript I have:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#testId").fadeOut(2000, function () {
            alert('animation complete');
        });

    });
```

I have also tried:

```
    $(function () {

        $("#testId").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            alert('animation complete');
        });

    });
```

and my image does not animate. it goes from 100% visible to 0%.

---

Edit

It does not work in any browser. I have tried google chrome, safari, and firefox.... It is really strange. I wish I can show you a video of my computer

Comment: Working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/PtBPe/ what browser are you in?

Comment: Your first example works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/D3fPS/

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 16.0.912.77 and FF9.0.1. Try one of the fiddle links in the comment.

Comment: I explained what I was doing wrong as a answer. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jquery before I could not understand what was going on!

I had 2 problems:

**1)**  I wanted to animate the image right when the page loaded so if you recall I did:

```
$(function () {

    $("#testId").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        alert('animation complete');
    });

});

$(function(){}) executes that function when the dom is done but the image was not loaded yet!. I have to animate the image latter.
```

**2)**  jquery library jquery-1.4.1.js was not working. I had to go to their site and download the latest version. Maybe I modified the file by accident.

### edit

I downloaded version jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js again in order to see if I modified the file by accident and with that version my animation does not work....

Answer (score 0):

Check below link which should help you.

http://www.viget.com/inspire/jquery-ie-png-24-ie-black-background-issue-solved/